# Deriving the standard errors for ML estimator of random effects

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model

Consider the random intercept model with one covariate:
$$
y_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{ij} + u_j + \epsilon_{ij}
$$
where $u_j \sim N(0,\sigma^2_u)$ and $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2_\epsilon)$

Consider the naive residual estimator.

$$\hat{u}_j = \frac{1}{n_j} \sum^{n_j}_{i=1} (y_{ij} - (\hat{\beta_0} + \beta_1 x_{ij} ))$$

where $\hat{\beta_0}$ and $\hat{\beta_1}$ are ML estimators.

Now, I came across the below derivation of the standard errors for estimator $\hat{u}_j$.

$$Var(\hat{u}_j) = Var( \frac{1}{n_j} \sum^{n_j}_{i=1} (y_{ij} - (\hat{\beta_0} + \beta_1 x_{ij} )) )\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$

Now what I do not understand is what follows, how did it go from above to below (1 -> 2).

$$=\frac{1}{n_j^2} Var(\sum^{n_j}_{i=1}y_{ij}) \;\;\;\;\; (2)$$
$$=\frac{1}{n_j^2} Var(\sum^{n_j}_{i=1}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{ij} + u_j + \epsilon_{ij})$$
$$=\frac{1}{n_j^2}(n^2_j\sigma^2_u + n_j \sigma^2_\epsilon)$$
$$=\sigma^2_u + \frac{\sigma^2_\epsilon}{n_j}$$

I understand everything after (2) but I just do not understand how it goes from (1) to (2). Can someone explain this to me please ?